# Parse record (PCF) from Kafka using Kafka Kusto Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-data-explorer

I've set-up my environment using docker based on [this guide](https://github.com/Azure/kafka-sink-azure-kusto/blob/master/README.md).

On kafka-console-producer I will send this line:

```
Hazriq|27|Undegrad|UNITEN
```

I want this data to be ingested to Kusto like this:

```
+--------+-----+----------------+------------+
| Name   | Age | EducationLevel | University |
+--------+-----+----------------+------------+
| Hazriq | 27  | Undegrad       | UNITEN     |
+--------+-----+----------------+------------+
```

Can this be handled by Kusto using the mapping (which I'm still trying to understand) or this should be catered by Kafka?

---

Tried @daniel suggestion:

```
.create table ParsedTable (name: string, age: int, educationLevel: string, univ:string)

.create table ParsedTable ingestion csv mapping 'ParsedTableMapping' '[{ "Name" : "name", "Ordinal" : 0},{ "Name" : "age", "Ordinal" : 1 },{ "Name" : "educationLevel", "Ordinal" : 2},{ "Name" : "univ", "Ordinal" : 3}]'
```

```
kusto.tables.topics_mapping=[{'topic': 'kafkatopiclugiaparser','db': 'kusto-test', 'table': 'ParsedTable','format': 'psv', 'mapping':'ParsedTableMapping'}]
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

but getting this instead:

```
+----------------------------+-----+----------------+------+
| Name                       | Age | EducationLevel | Univ |
+----------------------------+-----+----------------+------+
| Hazriq|27|Undergrad|UNITEN |     |                |      |
+----------------------------+-----+----------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the connector passes the data as it comes (no manipulation on it on the client side), and any parsing is left to Kusto.

As such, `psv` format is supported by kusto, and it should be possible by setting the format to `psv` and providing a mapping reference.

When adding the plugin as [described](https://github.com/Azure/kafka-sink-azure-kusto#add-plugin), you should be able to set it up like:

```
kusto.tables.topics_mapping=[{'topic': 'testing1','db': 'testDB', 'table': 'KafkaTest','format': 'psv', 'mapping':'KafkaMapping'}]
```

The mapping can be defined in Kusto as described in the Kusto docs [defined like so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/mappings#csv-mapping)

Comment: Hi Daniel. I've tried your suggestion with both `psv` and `csv` but I'm getting:

```
+----------------------------+-----+----------------+------+
| Name                       | Age | EducationLevel | Univ |
+----------------------------+-----+----------------+------+
| Hazriq|27|Undergrad|UNITEN |     |                |      |
+----------------------------+-----+----------------+------+
```

Comment: could you try sending a csv formatted value using the console-producer?  
Hazriq,27,Undegrad,UNITEN ? (it does require a restart for Kafka to pickup new settings)

Comment: The csv seems working. Managed to ingest it correctly. But not for psv.

Answer (score 0):

ingestion of data as you've shown using the `psv` format is supported (see below) - it's probably just a matter of debugging why your client-side invocation of the underlying commands aren't yielding the expected result. if you could share the full flow and code, including parameters, it may be helpful.

```
.create table ParsedTable (name: string, age: int, educationLevel: string, univ:string)

.ingest inline into table ParsedTable with(format=psv) <| Hazriq|27|Undegrad|UNITEN


ParsedTable:

| name   | age | educationLevel | univ   |
|--------|-----|----------------|--------|
| Hazriq | 27  | Undegrad       | UNITEN |
```